# Iterator for InputStream

Tags: java, iterator, inputstream

In a exercise, I have to create an iterator for an InputStream.
The goal is that the user can do :

```
for(byte b : new InputStreamToIterable(myInputStream)){
 //do stuff with byte
}
```

I finished to create it and it works well, but the Iterator `method` is not very elegant (lot of `try/catch`).

```
@Override
    public Iterator<Byte> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        try {
            return new Iterator<Byte>() {

                int data = is.read();
                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return data != -1;
                }

                @Override
                public Byte next() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(!hasNext()){
                        try {
                            is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    int a = data;
                    try {
                        data = is.read();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return (byte)a;
                }

                @Override
                public void remove() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            };
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to make it nicer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ...

- in method `next()`: unify the two try-catch blocks into a single one
- do the assignment `int data = is.read();` in a constructor, using a try-catch-block, and so get rid of the outermost try-catch-block.

When catching the IOExceptions, instead of simply calling `e.printStackTrace();` and continuing program execution, a better practice would be to enable users of this class to programmatically treat the error by re-throwing some RuntimeException (which needn't be declared and so doesn't violate the Iterable interface):

```
catch(IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could clean it up somewhat by combining the two `try-catch` blocks in `next()`:

```
boolean isClosed = false;
@Override
public Byte next() {
    if(isClosed) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    int a = data;
    try {
        if(!hasNext()) {
            is.close();
            isClosed = true;
        } else
            data = is.read();    
    } catch(IOException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
    return (byte)a;
}
```

**EDIT**
Changed the code according to discussion below

Comment: in the `!hasNext()` branch, a `NoSuchElementException` should be thrown according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Comment: If I close the stream, it's not compulsory to throw this exception, right ?

Comment: It should only be thrown if you try to access an element which isn't there, so basically if `next()` is called again after the `is.close()`.